I can't deploy my Token because of EVM version (?)
This is my code, I tried every evm version paris,berlin,istanbul etc. I can't figure out why it doesn't work. Also this is a school project that's why the version is very old we're using an old parent contract I believe.
This is the error:

Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The
transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Returned error: invalid opcode: CHAINID [object Object] The EVM
version used by the selected environment is not compatible with the
compiler EVM version.

pragma solidity =0.5.16;

import './interfaces/IUniswapV2ERC20.sol';
import 'contracts/libraries/SafeMath.sol';

contract AkalinsToken is IUniswapV2ERC20 {
    using SafeMath for uint;

    string public name = 'Akalin';   
    string public constant symbol = 'AKALIN'; 
    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;
    address[] private allHolders;    // save all the holders (there can be also addresses with 0 balance but every address is included only once
    
    
    uint  public totalSupply;
    mapping(address => uint) public balanceOf;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) public allowance;
    mapping(address => bool) private isHolder; // to check whether the address has been added to allHolders before

    bytes32 public DOMAIN_SEPARATOR;
    // keccak256("Permit(address owner,address spender,uint256 value,uint256 nonce,uint256 deadline)");
    bytes32 public constant PERMIT_TYPEHASH = 0x6e71edae12b1b97f4d1f60370fef10105fa2faae0126114a169c64845d6126c9;
    mapping(address => uint) public nonces;

    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event NameChanged(string newName);

    constructor() public {
        uint chainId;
        assembly {
            chainId := chainid
        }
        DOMAIN_SEPARATOR = keccak256(
            abi.encode(
                keccak256('EIP712Domain(string name,string version,uint256 chainId,address verifyingContract)'),
                keccak256(bytes(name)),
                keccak256(bytes('1')),
                chainId,
                address(this)
            )
        );
    }

    function _mint(address to, uint value) internal {
        totalSupply = totalSupply.add(value);
        balanceOf[to] = balanceOf[to].add(value);
        emit Transfer(address(0), to, value);
        if(!isHolder[to]){
            allHolders.push(to);
            isHolder[to] = true;
        }
    }

    function _burn(address from, uint value) internal {
        balanceOf[from] = balanceOf[from].sub(value);
        totalSupply = totalSupply.sub(value);
        emit Transfer(from, address(0), value);
    }

    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint value) private {
        allowance[owner][spender] = value;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, value);
    }

    function _transfer(address from, address to, uint value) private {
        balanceOf[from] = balanceOf[from].sub(value);
        balanceOf[to] = balanceOf[to].add(value);
        emit Transfer(from, to, value);
        if(!isHolder[to]){
            isHolder[to] = true;
            allHolders.push(to);
        }
       


    }

    function approve(address spender, uint value) external returns (bool) {
        _approve(msg.sender, spender, value);
        return true;
    }

    function transfer(address to, uint value) external returns (bool) {
        _transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) external returns (bool) {
        if (allowance[from][msg.sender] != uint(-1)) {
            allowance[from][msg.sender] = allowance[from][msg.sender].sub(value);
        }
        _transfer(from, to, value);
        return true;
    }

    function permit(address owner, address spender, uint value, uint deadline, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) external {
        require(deadline >= block.timestamp, 'UniswapV2: EXPIRED');
        bytes32 digest = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked(
                '\x19\x01',
                DOMAIN_SEPARATOR,
                keccak256(abi.encode(PERMIT_TYPEHASH, owner, spender, value, nonces[owner]++, deadline))
            )
        );
        address recoveredAddress = ecrecover(digest, v, r, s);
        require(recoveredAddress != address(0) && recoveredAddress == owner, 'UniswapV2: INVALID_SIGNATURE');
        _approve(owner, spender, value);
    }



        
    function findLargestHolder() internal view returns (address) {
        address largestHolder = address(0);
        uint largestBalance = 0;
        for (uint i = 0; i < allHolders.length; i++) {
            uint balance = balanceOf[allHolders[i]];
            if (balance > largestBalance) {
                largestBalance = balance;
                largestHolder = allHolders[i];
            }
        }
        return largestHolder;
    }
    
    modifier onlyLargestHolder() {
        require(msg.sender == findLargestHolder(), "Caller is not the largest holder");
        _;
    }
    // The person with the most balance can change the Tokens name
    function changeTokenName(string memory newName) public onlyLargestHolder {
     name = newName; 
     emit NameChanged(newName);
    
}






}


Environment is Injected Provider - MetaMask

For compiler version 0.5.16, any EVM version from berlin and below should work.

Make sure to check and align with the compiler versions used by the imported contracts and libraries.

None of the EVM versions work, unfortunately,

Can you share the compiler versions used by the imported contracts and libraries ?

pragma solidity >=0.5.0;
for
interface IUniswapV2ERC20 and pragma solidity 0.5.16; for library SafeMath. I can also deploy it to Remix VM (Cancun) but I cannot deploy it to out universities private blockchain. But since other students could do it I also dont think that the problem is about our private blockchain

@ErdemArifAkalin, are you able to deploy that on some testnet like sepolia or so ?
